# Não há opções de pagamento disponíveis

Tags: opencart

O problema é o seguinte: ao finalizar a compra como visitante (sem estar devidamente logado) a página de checkout exibe corretamente a opção de pagamento pelo PagSeguro, contudo ao realizar login na plataforma para finalizar o pedido, simplesmente a mensagem abaixo é exibida:

> Atenção: Não há opções de pagamento disponíveis. Entre em contato e informe os detalhes do pedido!

Obs.: já realizei atualização do módulo, pela loja oficial do OpenCart, para a versão 2.1.0.1. Os passos abaixo foram seguidos:

> 1. Certifique-se de que não há instalação de outros módulos para o
>          PagSeguro em seu sistema;
> 2. Baixe o repositório como arquivo zip ou
>          faça um clone;
> 3. Copie as pastas admin e catalog para dentro de sua
>          instalação OpenCart. Caso seja informado da sobrescrita de alguns
>          arquivos, você pode confirmar o procedimento sem problemas. Esta
>          instalação não afetará nenhum arquivo do seu sistema, somente
>          adicionará os arquivos do módulo PagSeguro;
> 4. Certifique-se de que as
>          permissões das pastas e arquivos recém copiados sejam,
>          respectivamente, definidas como 755 e 644;
> 5. Na área administrativa do
>          seu sistema, acesse o menu Extensions -> Payments -> PagSeguro ->
>          Install.

Comment: O problema estava no **endereço de cadastro do cliente** e ao finalizar o pedido o módulo do PagSeguro não era habilitado.